# EF5 Retrieving Nested Navigation Properties

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

Using .Net Framework 4, VB.Net, EF5, DbContext

Please consider three tables and their generated entities:

Company, Employee, Task

Task has a foreign key to Employee, Employee has a foreign key to Company.

In a partial class Company, how can I write a simple query which will return all Tasks within the Company?

To get all Tasks I am using this long-winded routine now:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Tasks As List(Of Task)
    Get
        Dim taskList = New List(Of Task)

        For Each e In Employees
            For Each t In e.Tasks
                taskList.Add(t)
            Next
        Next

        Return taskList
    End Get
End Property
```

Its performance is terrible. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ's SelectMany function (I'll try doing it here in VB, but you could look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) for an example of SelectMany if I get this wrong):

```
taskList = _ Companies.SelectMany(Function(c) _ c.Employees.SelectMany(Function(e) e.Tasks)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm writing this in a property within the Company class, I suppose it'd be:

```
Return Employees.SelectMany(Function(e) e.Tasks).ToList
```

This works and is a more efficient use of Object Services, so I'll mark your response as Answer.

It does, however, perform just as poorly as the loop I was using. I'll chalk it up to the SQL generated by the loop. I really don't feel like profiling it and looking - I'm sure it's a mess.

What I've done instead is this, within the Property:

```
Using context = New Entities
    Return context.Tasks.Where(Function(t) t.Employee.CompanyID = Me.CompanyID).ToList
End Using
```

This performs quite well. While I'm not really sure if it's considered good practice to query the context from within the Model project, I have decided to go this route.

Thanks very much.